# How can I use an old java applet with an expired certificate?

Tags: java, applet, certificate

We have been using a java applet from a 3rd party vendor for years. The vendor no longer exists. The certificate is expired and java is showing a warning message every time users access the applet.

Is there some way to mark the certificate or the JAR as being trusted so it doesn't keep warning users?

Comment: I don't know specifics on (re)signing an existing `.jar`, but a workaround to trust an untrusted certificate effectively breaks the whole security cert model.

Comment: @EJP is correct but will you please show us warning message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get yourself a new code signing certificate and sign the JAR file(s) yourself.